# google-api-php-client connect with key.p12

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

I'm able to add event to my google calendar with an API keys and OAuth 2.0 client IDs but I want to do this without the authorization screen of google.

I followed the information found on this post:

stackoverflow.com/questions/8995451/how-do-i-connect-to-the-google-calendar-api-without-the-oauth-authentication

For this, I created a 'Service account keys'. I went to my project credentials and select 'Create Credentials > Service Account Key'

Then:

service account > my_project_name

Key type > p12

I saved the key file key.p12

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// display error, debbug
ini_set('display_errors',1);

session_start();

require_once './google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once './google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

// following values are taken from : console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=projectname credentials
// OAuth 2.0 client IDs : Client ID
const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx';
// Service account keys : Service account
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'my_project_name';

// key 
const KEY_FILE = './key.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Quickstart");

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
    $key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

//Save token in session
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

// my code here
$event = new Google_Event(...
$calendarId = 'mycalendarID@group.calendar.google.com';
$event = $cal->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

?>
```

And here is the error message:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  'error' : 'invalid_client',
  'error_description' : 'The OAuth client was not found.'
}' in /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(264): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
#1 /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(218): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion()
#2 /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#3 /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php(469): Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array)
#4 /home/www/goog in /home/www/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288
```

It seems that the $client->getAccessToken() isn't set but I don't know why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create service account key and download the *.json file that contains private keys. Put the *.json file you just downloaded in a directory of your choosing ( `credentials.json` file in the example ). Then go to Google Calendar->Share and add service account id on the list.

```
putenv( 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json' );

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' );
$client->setHttpClient( new GuzzleHttp\Client( [ 'verify' => false ] ) );   // disable ssl if necessary

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar( $client );  

// list events
$service->events->listEvents( $calendar_id, array( 'timeMin' => ( new DateTime )->format( DateTime::RFC3339 ) ) );

// add event
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event( $data );
$event = $service->events->insert( $calendar_id, $event );
```

You can find the Google APIs PHP Client Library package with autoloader in the [releases](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) page on GitHub, so the only `require_once` call necessary is for autoload file:

```
require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And, [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) may help you further, this is just one way that works for me so it may be useful to you as well.

Comment: thanks Danijel for your answer. I created a new service account credentials with role > project > owner. I downloaded the file and placed it in the root directory of my webserer. I'm stucked at 'Then go to Google Calendar->Share and add service account id on the list.' I went to my google account calendar > settings > calendar > mycalendar > Calendar Address > share settings > Share with specific people , here I tried to enter the 'service account key ID' with no success. It requests an email addr. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it wrong, got to "Manage service accounts", and use "Service account ID", not "Key ID", my mistake.